# Array of array subtraction in scala

Tags: scala

I'm learning the ropes of Scala, and am wondering if there is an easy way to do array subtraction.

Let's say I have two arrays where elements are of the form (K,V):

```
A: Array((1,2), (2,3), (4,1))
B: Array((1,1), (2,3))
```

I would like to get

```
A - B: Array((1,1), (4,1))
```

The corresponding keys should subtract.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Seems like the word "subtract" is confusing. What I wish to do is to subtract values of matching keys in (K, V) pairs in the arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean you want to subtract B from A for every matching key, and if the difference is 0, ignore it, then do this:

```
val a = Array((1,2), (2,3), (4,1))
val b = Array((1,1), (2,3))

val bMap = b.toMap
a.map{ case (k,v) => (k, v - bMap.getOrElse(k,0)) }.filter(_._2 != 0)
// Array((1,1), (4,1))
```

This procedure converts `b` to a map for easy lookup.  Then we traverse `a` and, for each element, subtract `b`'s value for that key (or 0 if it's not there).  Finally, we remove any entries in the result that have a value of 0.

Comment: thanks. But that won't subtract them isn't it? The answer I want is ((1,1), (4,1))

Comment: @Andy, what's your definition of "subtract"?  I assumed you meant something like set difference...

Comment: I have edited the question. I wish to subtract corresponding values for matching keys in (K, V) pairs in the array.

Answer (score 6):

This is usually a set operation, so if order isn't important, you might try using sets. Then it would just be something like `A.toSet -- B.toSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the "for expression":

```
val a = Array((1,2), (2,3), (4,1))
val b = Array((1,1), (2,3))

val bMap = b.toMap
for {
  (k, v) <- a                      // get an element from a
  nv =  v - bMap.getOrElse(k,0)    // calculate the new value
  if (nv > 0)                      // filter the 0 values
} yield (k, nv)                    // yield the updated pair
```